# Retrieving values from MS SQL using Hibernate without performing Create of the C.R.U.D operation

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, crud

Let's say I have this existing data in MS SQL,

**debt**

```
  id          can           bdrl_debt    excess_ta_debt      posting_ref   debt_settlement_id   debt_settlement_at       debt_business_date
  
11425   1099112400000003        0              200             501728             137        2020-10-13 10:51:50.000         2020-10-13
```

How do I retrieve and print out the data in such a way that I do not have to perform the Create of the C.R.U.D operation? Can anybody enlighten me on how to do that?

Note: Connection is fine. I'm using `AnnotationMapping` with `Entity` Class.

Comment: Is there a way to do it? I've seen examples where I've to manually create it before I retrieve it but I don't want to do that since the server is on cloud. Is there any other way to do it apart from `Hibernate` POJO Annotation Mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to retrieve the data from `MS SQL` using `String` to map variables with the database.

Here is the snippet of the output:

```
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=137, debt_id=11432, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-13 10:51:50.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=560820}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11476, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=618301}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=167, debt_id=11553, bdrl_debt=100, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:47:33.0, excess_ta_debt=0, posting_ref=686423}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11477, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=618302}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11510, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=881207}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=167, debt_id=11554, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:47:33.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=686424}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11512, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=703795}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11472, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=729918}
13:55:59.553 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11473, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=729919}
13:55:59.554 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11474, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=814333}
13:55:59.554 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=165, debt_id=11551, bdrl_debt=100, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:46:50.0, excess_ta_debt=100, posting_ref=767375}
13:55:59.554 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=137, debt_id=11431, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-13 10:51:50.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=560819}
13:55:59.554 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11518, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=689525}
13:55:59.580 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11519, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=689526}
13:55:59.580 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=169, debt_id=11557, bdrl_debt=100, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:52:57.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=772352}
13:55:59.580 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11514, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=699984}
13:55:59.580 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=169, debt_id=11558, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:52:57.0, excess_ta_debt=600, posting_ref=772353}
13:55:59.581 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=138, debt_id=11438, bdrl_debt=100, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-13 10:54:50.0, excess_ta_debt=0, posting_ref=773108}
13:55:59.581 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=160, debt_id=11515, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 12:08:20.0, excess_ta_debt=200, posting_ref=699985}
13:55:59.581 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=169, debt_id=11559, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-14, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-14 13:52:57.0, excess_ta_debt=600, posting_ref=772354}
13:55:59.581 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtDebtbbyCAN{debt_can=1099112400000003, debt_settlement_id=138, debt_id=11439, bdrl_debt=0, debt_business_date=2020-10-13, debt_settlement_at=2020-10-13 10:54:50.0, excess_ta_debt=500, posting_ref=773109}
13:55:59.581 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - More......
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.debt")
public class AbtDebtbbyCAN implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int debt_id;

    @Column(name = "can")
    private int debt_can;

    @Column(name = "bdrl_debt")
    private int bdrl_debt;

    @Column(name = "excess_ta_debt")
    private int excess_ta_debt;

    @Column(name = "posting_ref")
    private int posting_ref;

    @Column(name = "debt_settlement_id")
    private int debt_settlement_id;

    @Column(name = "debt_settlement_at")
    private String debt_settlement_at;

    @Column(name = "debt_business_date")
    private String debt_business_date;

}
```

In order for it to be printed in the output, make sure the variables are using `String` data type so it could be deserialized. Hope this answers your question.